# Does the existence of "gravitational waves" (assuming they exist) imply that time exists as a 4th dimension in the universe?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, gravitational-waves

I'm new to thinking about special and general relativity and I have no formal training as a physicist. However, I've been doing a bit of thinking about spacetime recently. I was wondering if "gravitational waves" provide evidence that spacetime accurately describes the structure of the universe. Or, in other words, do "gravitational waves" provide evidence that time exists as a 4th dimension in the universe (and what that implies  about past, present, and future events in 3D space all existing with equal reality)?

Please keep in mind, I'm not asking for opinions (or dogmatic assertions) about the accuracy of universe-as-spacetime-continuum theory per se. I'm asking if "gravitational waves" logically imply the universe-as-spacetime-continuum theory.

Comment: Are you asking that time exists as a spatial dimension or not?

Comment: Gravity waves are another verification of a prediction made by General Relativity. Previous confirmations of General relativity include the precession of the orbit of Mercury, bending of starlight by the Sun's gravitational field, time dialation for GPS satellite signals and various other previous confirmations for predictions made by General relativity. So far, the theory has held up to scientific scrutiny for the past 100 years. Fundamental to GR is that spacetime is a four dimensional non-Euclidian manifold which includes time as one of the dimensions.

Comment: The geometric treatment of time in relativity is a convenience that should not deflect from the fact that time is fundamentally different from space. Gravitational waves change absolutely nothing about that.

Comment: I'm not asking if time exists as a spatial dimension or if time exists as a 4th dimension (spatial or otherwise) or if spacetime accurately describes the structure of the universe or if any other theory is true or false. I'm specifically asking whether or not the presence of gravitational waves in the universe logically implies that spacetime does in fact accurately describe the structure of universe. I'm assuming that the two statements "spacetime accurately describes the structure of the universe" and "time exists as a 4th dimension in the universe" are logically equivalent.

Comment: CuriousOne, are you essential saying that the empirical observation of gravitational waves does nothing to confirm that spacetime is an accurate description of the structure of the universe?

Comment: We know that spacetime is not an accurate description, so confirming that it is is not even on the menu. Why do we know that? Because general relativity can not give you matter anymore than Newtonian mechanics can. It is a very limited theory that seems to do one thing very well: describe gravity on scales the size of the solar system and up. Other than that it can't do anything.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's a bit too far. Obviously we apply GR to the gravitational wave detectors which are much smaller than the solar system. We also apply GR to GPS satellites. The effects of GR can be small so you might need precision systems to have predictions that aren't swamped by modeling errors. But accurate enough rulers and accurate enough clocks and GR is detectable. There aren't magic scales of size where QM turns off or where GR turns on.

Comment: @Timaeus: We know that Newtonian gravity (i.e. the quasi-static weak field limit of GR) works all the way down to one mm (probably a little lower than that) the way we expect. That's not the problem. The problem is that from there absolutely nothing is known about gravity (except maybe that it's weak, but even that could be false). Nobody expects gravity to turn off... it just doesn't do a thing within the measurable limits and GR doesn't give us any useful hints of what, if anything, it may be doing there. GR is what it is, and nothing more. It would be nice if it could do more, but it can't.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's misleading and actually wrong. We know that if your measurement devices are crude enough you can't distinguish between curved spacetime and Newtonian gravity. But with good measurement devices you can tell the difference. Nature only provides a cut off in the sense that science is hard work, so every tool has limitations. GR doesn't have difficulty predicting at 1mm. Experimentalists have difficulty measuring the super small things GR predicts. And that's because the predicted effects are small. Just like how relativity applies at low speeds.

Comment: @peter "gravity waves" are a completely different (and mundane) phenomenon.

Comment: I would love to hear more about how "we know that spacetime is not an accurate description." Do others agree with this statement?

Comment: @lostinthecloud I think by that he meant simply that the theory rarely perfectly fits the reality.  To say that the earth is a sphere would be wrong, because it is larger around the equator.  To call it an ellipsis would still be wrong, because it is hardly a perfect ellipsis, but it would be a more accurate theory.  The reality is far more complicated, with mountains and man-made structures..  in that regard, we'll likely never ever *prove* spacetime correct, and yet gravitational waves were searched *because* spacetime suggested the possibility.

Comment: I don't see how the existence of time as a fourth dimension have anything to do with gravitational waves....note that gravitational waves is a consequence of GR, which in turn is a consequence of spacetime; i.e. we already IMPLY the existence of time as a fourth dimension before working on stuff like gravitational waves.

Comment: I cannot recall the proof or find my notes on thus will post this as a comment  instead of an answer. For gravity to propagate the metric has at least four degrees of freedom meaning the universe in which we live is at least four dimensional.

Comment: For there to be "evidence" of "time existing as a 4th dimension", you have to say what it *means* for "time to exist as a 4th dimension". If you just mean that general relativity's description of spacetime as a 4D manifold with one time-like direction is correct, well, we had sufficient evidence for that even before detecting gravitational waves.

Comment: It seems to me that it could be the case that representing time as a 4th dimension in an imaginary "4D manifold of spacetime" is useful as a mathematical model, but that it may not accurately describe the universe. What I seem to be hearing is that the detection of GW does not provide any additional evidence to confirm the universe-as-spacetime-continuum theory, and that without the theory as a starting place, the data that is believed to confirm the presence of GW would be interpreted differently (and would not itself inspire theories involving the universe being composed of spacetime). Yes?

Comment: What is the difference between a mathematical model that is useful in the sense that it predicts every possible measurement result correctly and something that "accurately describes the universe"? At the end of the day, *all* our theories are just mathematical models that are useful to predict what happens. That's what physics is about.

Comment: If we assume spacetime accurately describes the universe, time travel may be possible, including time travel into the past (i.e. via wormholes). However, if we see spacetime as only a useful model and another explanation exists for all observable phenomena, we may be less likely to believe that time travel is possible. Just because we can plot some variables against each other on a graph and the math works out doesn't mean that graph describes the fabric of the universe. There were geocentric models of the solar system that more or less worked before Copernicus came along.

Comment: That is not (necessarily) true, since *not all allowed solutions may be realized*. The wormhole solutions to the Einstein Field Equations may well be simply unphysical, and that'd be the end of that. I think that in the theoretical physics community it's widely accepted that GR will eventually be superseded by a theory that will incorporate quantum effects, and it's definitely not the case that gravitational waves rule this out.

Answer (score 13):

The successful observation of gravitational waves$^1$ provides very strong support for the statement that Einstein's theory of general relativity accurately describes the behavior of masses interacting in our Universe.
The dimensional nature of time plays an important conceptual role in the arguments which lead to general relativity --- and, for that matter, special relativity, which has had many, many, many more successful tests.

Any future theory of gravity must now predict gravitational waves, in addition to describing Mercury's orbital precession, centimeter-scale details of the libration of the moon, the aberration of starlight by the sun, gravitational lensing, length contraction and time dilaton, etc.

I am too cautious to rule out the possibility that some future paradigm shift will treat the time dimensions more differently from the space dimensions than relativity does.  But even if that happens, the relativity we have now will remain a powerful tool for thinking about the behavior of the world, just like Newton's outdated laws are such useful conceptual tools and give such useful approximations that most students still spend a year doing Newton before moving on to Einstein.

---

$^1$
Note that [gravity waves](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/fz141.htm) are a little more prosaic.

Comment: What does "centimeter-scale details of the libration of the moon" mean? Google finds me nothing.

Comment: @KDecker That the moon is getting farther from the Earth by about 3.8 centimeters per year.

Comment: @KDecker Newton's gravity and Einstein's gravity predict the location and orientation of the moon due to its [libration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration) with differences of about ten meters.  In the last ten years it has become possible to measure the moon's location [with millimeter precision](http://www.physics.ucsd.edu/~tmurphy/apollo/apollo.html), which means the difference between classical and relativistic gravity has now been tested to five significant figures.  [A review](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2010-7/).

Comment: Libration is a balance-like moving of the moon within the Earth's gravity field. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration] Wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

Gravitational waves (GW) is one more phenomenon just like many other relativistic phenomena that confirm existence of spacetime (whatever it is defined as). Spacetime has already been confirmed for example, by atomic clocks having different tick rates on earth, and in orbits. There have been number of experiments including one done by NASA about frame dragging. GW was not necessary to prove spacetime. It was a prediction made by GR, which is now proved to be a fact per the recent observation.